# Как решить проблему использования переменной из одной функции в другой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Нужно чтобы вводимое сообщение в переписке `ВК-ботом` отправлялось сразу от(?) `ВК-бота` в *DialogFlow*. А ответ от *DialogFlow* автоматически являлся ответом от `ВК-бота`.Объясните пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка.

```py
    def send_message(message):
        request = apiai.ApiAI('token').text_request()
        request.lang = 'ru'
        request.session_id = 'session_1'
        request.query = message
        responseJson = json.loads(request.getresponse().read().decode('utf-8'))
        response = responseJson['result']['fulfillment']['speech']
        return response
        send_message(input(request))

    def write_msg(user_id, message):
        vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random.getrandbits(64)})

    arg = send_message(response)

    # API-ключ Вконтакте
    token = "ключ"

    # Авторизуемся как сообщество Вконтакте 
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

    # Работа с сообщениями
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
    #если авторизация успешно прошла, присылаем сообщение в консоль о том, что бот запущен
    print("Бот запущен")

    # Основной цикл
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.to_me:
                # Сообщение от пользователя
                request = event.text
                # Стандартная логика ответа черещ оператор If
                if request == "привет" or "Привет!":
                    write_msg(event.user_id, arg)
                elif request == "пока":
                    write_msg(event.user_id, "Всего самого хорошего!")
                else:
```

Comment: Кто понял вопрос - отзовись!

Comment: я попробовал переписать вопрос, но вроде лучше не стало..